# Error in recognizing space vs number in following assembly program

Tags: assembly

I have following assembly program that needs to print the message "You have entered a space" when user simply enters space in the input field. And, should print the message "you have entered a number" when user inputs a number.

My problem is that it is printing "You have entered a space" all the time even when I enter a number.  Please advise what am I doing wrong in the following program.

Thank you.

```
@ homework7.s

mov r0, #65
mov r7, #1
swi 0

.text
    .globl main
main:



@ Display your First and Last name
@ Display homework 7
@ Display theia or pi


mov r7, #4
mov r0, #1
mov r2, #12
LDR R1, = string
swi 0

.data
string:
.ascii "John Smith \n" 

.text

@ Prompt user to enter a character.
    MOV R0, #1
    MOV R2, #26
    MOV R7, #4
    LDR R1, =prompt
    SWI 0
    
        
@ Get the input

    MOV R0, #1
    MOV R2, #5
    MOV R7, #3
    LDR R1, =sid
    SWI 0    
    
@ Get the character

 LDR R1, =sid
 LDR R2, [R1]
 AND R3, R2, #255


@ Else if character is an Ascii value for a number 0 through 9 //problem
@ Then 
 
    CMP R3, #48
    BEQ number
    
    CMP R3, #49
    BEQ number

    CMP R3, #50
    BEQ number
    
    CMP R3, #51
    BEQ number

    CMP R3, #52
    BEQ number
    
    CMP R3, #53
    BEQ number

    CMP R3, #54
    BEQ number

    CMP R3, #55
    BEQ number

    CMP R3, #56
    BEQ number

    CMP R3, #57
    BEQ number


@   Display message "You entered a number"

number: 
    MOV R0, #1
    MOV R2, #24
    MOV R7, #4
    LDR R1, =number1
    SWI 0 
    

exit:
    MOV R7, #1
    SWI 0

.data
prompt:
.ascii " Please enter a character\n "

sid:
.ascii "     " 

.data
space1:
.ascii "You've entered a space\n"

.data
 number1:
.ascii "You've entered a number\n"
```

Comment: You only check if the character is `49`, which is `'1'`. If you enter anything but a space or a `1`, your code will fall through the the `space` part of your program anyways. You need to check if the character is in the range `48` to `57`, and add a default case for if it's neither a space nor a number.

Comment: Thank you for the hint Thomas.  Regarding following ", and add a default case for if it's neither a space nor a number. "

How do I add the default case to implement if its  neither a space nor a number?

Comment: Hi Thomas,  I have put the revised code in the original post following your instructions.  However not sure where the default condition would fit as I am not sure how to use it without switch statement.

Comment: While checking each digit individually works, it's not ideal. Ignoring that, it looks like you've completely removed the check and printing for a space. The default case would be whatever code falls immediately after the checks and branches.